# How to get a date in the format "2020-01-10T08: 47: 36.264Z"?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am trying to get a date in the format "2020-01-10T08: 47: 36.264Z", but I have not succeeded, I try to use the toIso8601String (), toUtc (), toLocal () method, but I do not return the format required.
I am new to flutter.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Can you explain how `toIso8601String` doesn't do what you want?  How is its output different than what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

To format a date in Flutter, you can follow this step:

Import the intl package.

Create a method to format your date like this.

String formatDate(DateTime date) { DateFormat formatter = DateFormat ('yyyy-MM-dd');
return formatter.format(date); }

So you will go to where you want to format your date and call the formatDate method and pass your date.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss').format(now);
```